# Updating array from localStorage

Tags: jquery, local-storage

Not sure but there is a breakdown in my code here. I am working on taking the value a person enters in a textbox with JQuery and adding it to an array stored in local storage.

http://jsfiddle.net/pnewelljr/jqdkfLdx/46/

```
        var items = JSON.parse(localStorage[itemsid]);
        items.push(value);
        localStorage[itemsid] = JSON.stringify(items);
```

Comment: that should be okay..

Comment: It seems to break it though because it doesn't go to the next line of the function. It is supposed to remove the textbox, and when I add this line of code the textbox is no longer removed.

Comment: And it also doesn't seem to be adding it to the array, because when I click the list name on the right, it resets the list to default.

Comment: Figured it out, I didn't set an initial itemsid at the top.